# Aggregate one table twice on different level

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am a little bit a newbie in SQL and am struggling with a seemingly easy task.
Let's see the data:

```
FirstName LastName     ID           DepartmentNumber    ManagerID
Aliana    Abramova     1111111111   4                   4610226861
Boriana   Borova       2222222222   4                   4610226861
Cali      Moldovanska  3333333333   4                   4610226861
Anelia    Simeonova    4009016246   1                   4009016246
Maria     Tacheva      4206174562   3                   4206174562
```

This is an employee table. What I am trying to do is to extract these employees that are managers (ID = ManagerID) but only these out of them that work in a department that have more than one employees (so only these that have a count of ID grouped by DepartmentNumber >0)

I can do this tasks separately:

```
Select FirstName, LastName, ID 
from Employee 
where ID = ManagerID;

Select count(ID) 
from Employee 
group by DepartmentNumber;
```

It is hard for me though, to somehow merge this knowledge into one query and combined the data so that I know which are these IDs that belong to employees that are both managers and in their department work more than 1 person.

I have done similar tasks but when it comes to merging 1-2-3 tables grouped on different levels (and merged by different keys) I get somehow confused. Probably I need to make an interim select statement but now sure how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.YourTable A
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM dbo.YourTable 
             WHERE DepartmentNumber = A.DepartmentNumber
             GROUP BY DepartmentNumber
             HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) 
AND ID = ManagerID;
```

Comment: Hey, great - I believe it works! Much appreciated.How do you interpret Select 1 (what does 1 stand for) in the exists statement?

Comment: I believe that is just selecting the first column from the result set

Comment: @Bullzeye It's not selecting the first column, just the literal value `1`. It could have been `SELECT *`, `SELECT somecolumn`, `SELECT NULL` etc. It's just checking the existence of the row, and I use `SELECT 1` to show explicitly that I don't need any columns from that subquery